Unable to query windows process from ansible
I am working on ansible playbook where I need to add remote desktop session host on current RDS deployment. I am running below command to start servermanager process on remote server via ansible:
 Invoke-CimMethod Win32_Process -MethodName create -Arguments @{CommandLine="C:\Windows\System32\ServerManager.exe /p"}

It is working fine and process is being launched on remote server. I tried logging to remote server and opened task manager. I can see the process is running in task manager under details tab with my user name. But If I go to Users tab, I don't see the process under my username.
It might be because of process launched in non-interactive session and I am looking at task manager using interactive session.
Since launching process is working fine from ansible. But when I query same process from same ansible module using below command, it doesn't work and it gives the error:
Get-CimInstance -Query 'Select * from Win32_Process where name like "servermanager%"' - ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ComputerName $servername

Error: A specified logon does not exist it may already have been terminated

It seems double hop issue from ansible. Can anyone help me to find the solution for this. Though remote query is working fine from other server. It is the issue via ansible only.

Anyone has any inputs at above query. I would appreciate that.
